# MySQL Error: file " <dict>" not found when booting

Tags: mysql

So, for portability and testing purposes I have set up an SQL server to run off of a flash drive, which I am aware is not exactly the best idea in the world, however until now, it has worked just fine. Whenever I attempt to start the SQL Server I get this

this is error_log2.err

```
mysqld: File '  <dict>' not found (OS errno 2 - No such file or directory)
2019-09-11T13:38:49.003007Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] D:\mysql\mysql-8.0.17-winx64\bin\mysqld.exe (mysqld 8.0.17) starting as process 10444
2019-09-11T13:38:53.330810Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010958] [Server] Could not open log file.
2019-09-11T13:38:53.330864Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010041] [Server] Can't init tc log
2019-09-11T13:38:53.340276Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2019-09-11T13:38:54.702951Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] D:\mysql\mysql-8.0.17-winx64\bin\mysqld.exe: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.17)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
```

The problem seems to be with file `'   <dict>'` however, I am not sure exactly what this entails. Any suggestions on fixing this error? Thanks for any suggestions

here's my config.ini

```
[mysqld]
sql_mode = NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES
basedir = "D:\\mysql\\mysql-8.0.17-winx64"
datadir = "D:\\mysql\\mydb"
port = "55555"
log-error = "D:\\mysql\\logs\\error_log2.err"

[mysqladmin]
user = "root"
port = "55555"
```

Comment: Check service command line. Check MySQL INI file (my.ini ?). Search for a token which causes this error, and set proper value into it. Another variant - log file exists, but is not visible to server process. You may simply delete/rename it - it will be re-created.

Comment: I added the config.ini which is used while starting sql, removing the comments. I dont see anything wrong, ill also look  for the other log

Comment: Please show MySQL service command line in addition.